# Definite Parity of Solutions to a Schrödinger Equation with even Potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, schroedinger-equation, parity

I am reading up on the Schrödinger equation and I quote:

> *Because the potential is symmetric under $x\to-x$, we expect that there will be solutions of definite parity.*

Could someone kindly explain why this is true? And perhaps also what it means physically?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Good question! First you need to know that [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29) refers to the behavior of a physical system, or one of the mathematical functions that describe such a system, under reflection. There are two "kinds" of parity:

- If $f(x) = f(-x)$, we say the function $f$ has even parity
- If $f(x) = -f(-x)$, we say the function $f$ has odd parity

Of course, for most functions, neither of those conditions are true, and in that case we would say the function $f$ has *indefinite* parity.

Now, have a look at the time-independent Schrödinger equation in 1D:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\psi(x) + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$$

and notice what happens when you reflect $x\to -x$:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\psi(-x) + V(-x)\psi(-x) = E\psi(-x)$$

If you have a symmetric (even) potential, $V(x) = V(-x)$, this is *exactly* the same as the original equation except that we've transformed $\psi(x) \to \psi(-x)$. Since the two functions $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(-x)$ satisfy the same equation, you should get the same solutions for them, except for an overall multiplicative constant; in other words,

$$\psi(x) = a\psi(-x)$$

Normalizing $\psi$ requires that $|a| = 1$, which leaves two possibilities: $a = +1$ (even parity) and $a = -1$ (odd parity).

As for what this means physically, it tells you that whenever you have a symmetric potential, you should be able to find a basis of eigenstates which have definite even or odd parity (though I haven't proved that here,* only made it seem reasonable). In practice, you get linear combinations of eigenstates with different parities, so the actual state may not actually be symmetric (or antisymmetric) around the origin, but it does at least tell you that if your potential is symmetric, you *could* construct a symmetric (or antisymmetric) state. That's not guaranteed otherwise. You'd probably have to get input from someone else as to what exactly definite-parity states are used for, though, since that's out of my area of expertise (unless you care about parity of elementary particles, which is rather weirder).

---

*There is a parity operator $P$ that reverses the orientation of the space: $Pf(x) = f(-x)$. Functions of definite parity are eigenfunctions of this operator. I believe you can demonstrate the existence of a definite-parity eigenbasis by showing that $[H,P] = 0$.

Comment: Ooh, btw why can't $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|a|=1$?

Comment: Doing reflection twice, you get $a^2 =1$ so it is a real number.

Comment: @IanDsouza The point is that you get the _same_ particular solutions to $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(-x)$. My answer isn't saying that $\psi(x) = \pm \psi(-x)$ for _all_ solutions, only that one _can find_ solutions which satisfy that criterion (which is what the question was asking for).

Comment: @IanDsouza: If you found a stationary solution $\psi(x)$, the function $\psi(-x)$ will also be a solution with the same energy. In other words, as David said, $\psi_n(x)=\pm\psi_n(-x)$.

Comment: As other answers point out, "Since the two functions [...] satisfy the same [second order linear differential] equation, you should get the same solutions for them, except for an overall multiplicative constant" is not true in general. Assuming continuity of $\psi$, the relevant uniqueness theorem requires that the function and its derivative be specified at a certain point for there to be a unique solution (up to a multiplicative constant). An easy solution is to use the fact that $\psi(x)=\psi(-x)$ and $\psi'(x)=\psi'(-x)$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 15):

Sorry I found David Z' answer a bit confused just when discussing the crucial point.

> Since the two functions ψ(x) and ψ(−x) satisfy the same equation, you should get the same solutions for them, except for an overall multiplicative constant; in other words,
>
> ψ(x)=aψ(−x)
>
> Normalizing ψ requires that |a|=1, which leaves two possibilities: a=+1 (even >parity) and a=−1 (odd parity).

The first part "Since the two functions... multiplicative constant" is generally false without an important *further* requirement that is not garanted here. It is indeed true under the hypothesis that the eigenspace of the Hamiltonian operator with eigenvalue $E$ we are considering is *one-dimensional*. However this is not the case in general. Finally the remaining part of the statement above "Normalizing ... parity)." is incorrect anyway as it stands: normalization just requires $|a|=1$.

Let me propose an alternative answer.

First of all, one introduces the *parity transformation*, $P: {\cal H} \to {\cal H}$, where ${\cal H} = L^2(R)$, defined as follows *without referring to any Hamiltonian operator*:

$$(P\psi)(x):= \eta_\psi \psi(-x)\:.$$

Above $\eta_\psi$ is a complex number with $|\eta_\psi|=1$. *It is necessary* to leave this possibility because, as is well known in QM, *states are wavefunctions up to a phase* so that  $\phi$ and $e^{i\alpha} \phi$ are indistinguishable  as states and, physically, we can only handle states. As the map $P$ is (1) *bijective* and (2) it *preserves the probabilities of transition between states*, it is a so-called *quantum symmetry*. A celebrated theorem by Wigner guarantees that every quantum symmetry can be represented by either an unitary or an antiunitary operator (depending on the nature of the symmetry itself). In the present case all that means that  it must be possible to fix the map $\psi \mapsto \eta_\psi$ in order that $P$ becomes *linear* (or anti-linear) and *unitary* (or anti-unitary). As a matter of fact $P$ becomes unitary if $\eta$ is assumed to be independent form $\psi$. So we end up with the *unitary parity operator*:

$$(P\psi)(x):= \eta \psi(-x) \quad \psi \in L^2(R)$$

where $\eta \in C$ with $|\eta|=1$ is any *fixed* number. We can make more precise our choice of $\eta$ requiring that $P$ is also an *observable*, that is $P=P^\dagger$. It is immediate to verify that it happens only for $\eta = \pm 1$. It is matter of convenience to fix the sign. We henceforth assume $\eta=1$ (nothing follows would change with the other choice). We have our parity observable/symmetry given by:

$$(P\psi)(x):= \psi(-x) \quad \psi \in L^2(R)$$

What is the spectrum of $P$? As $P$ is unitary, the elements $\lambda$ of the spectrum  must verify $|\lambda|=1$. As $P$ is self-adjoint the spectrum has to belong in the real line. We conclude that the spectrum of $P$ contains $\{-1,1\}$ at most. Since these are discrete points they must be proper eigenvalues with associated proper eigenvectors (I mean :Things like Dirac's delta are excluded).

It is impossible that the spectrum contains $1$ only or  $-1$ only, otherwise we would have $P=I$ or $P=-I$ respectively, that is evidently false.  We have found that $P$ has exactly two eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$.

At this point we can define a state, represented by $\psi$, to have *even parity* if $P\psi = \psi$ or  *odd parity* if $P\psi = -\psi$.

Let us come to the problem with our Hamiltonian. If $V(x) = V(-x)$, by direct inspection one immediately sees that:

$$[P, H] =0\:.$$

Assuming that the spectrum of $H$ is a pure point spectrum (otherwise we can restrict ourselves to deal with the Hilbert space associated with the point spectrum of $H$ disregarding that associated with the continuous one), a known theorem assures that there is a Hilbert basis of eigenvectors of $H$ and $P$ simultaneously.

If $\psi_E$ is such a common eigenvector (associated with the eigenvalue $E$ of $H$), it must verify either $P\psi_E= \psi_E$ or   $P\psi_E= -\psi_E$, namely:

$\qquad\qquad \qquad \psi_E(-x) = \psi_E(x)$ or, respectively, $\psi_E(-x)= -\psi_E(x)$.

To conclude, I stress that it is generally false that an eigenvector of $H$ has defined parity. If the eigenspace of the given eigenvalue has dimension $\geq 2$, it is easy to construct counterexamples.
It is necessarily true, however, if the considered eigenspace of $H$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: Why it is not generally true for higher dimensions? Which part of your argument requires 1-dimension restriction?

Comment: Suppose that the eigenspace ${\cal H}_E$ with eigenvalue $E$ of $H$ is two-dimensional (this  argument more gemerally works for dimension $\geq 2$). Since $H$ commutes with $P$ there must be a Hilbertian basis of eigenvectors of $P$ of ${\cal H}_E$, say $\psi_+, \psi_-$ with $P\psi_\pm = \pm \psi_\pm$. With this situation, $\psi := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\psi_+ + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \psi_-$ satisfies $H\psi=E\psi$ but it is not an eigevector of $P$: It has not defined parity. Both $\psi(-x) = \psi(x)$ and $\psi(-x)= -\psi(x)$ are false.

Comment: But the question is to show 'we expect that there will be solutions of definite parity.' We can certainly construct definite-parity solutions in the example you give, it is just that not every solution satisfies.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. My point, at the end of my answer was different: that not all eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian operator are eigenvectors of the parity operator.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should be an alternative answer from first principles.

Assume the Hamiltonian is one dimensional, and $V(x)$ is an even function. Given a general solution $\psi (x)$, we also have that $\psi (-x)$ is a solution. If the eigenspace of the Hamiltonian is one dimensional, then we must have
$$
\psi (x) = \alpha \psi ( -x)
$$
where $|\alpha | = 1$.
Multiply both sides by $\overline{\psi (x) }$ and integrate over $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\int _{- \infty} ^{\infty} \mathrm{d} x \ \overline{\psi (x) }\psi (x) = \alpha \int _{- \infty} ^{\infty} \mathrm{d} x \ \overline{\psi (x) }\psi (-x)  
$$
It is straightforward to show by changing variables $ x=-z$ that the integral on the right hand side is equal to its complex conjugate, and hence it's real. Because the left hand side is equal to $1$, then we must have that $ \alpha = \pm 1$.

If $ \psi (x) $ and $ \psi (-x) $ are linearly independent, then I don't know how to deal with the situation.

Please let me know if you have found a flaw in my argument. Cheers.

Comment: In 1D, there are no degenerate eigenstates. So there can't be a linearly independent $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(-x)$. Since they have the same energy, they must be the same state!