# Is a non-degenerate wavefunction real or complex?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

[In this video](http://youtu.be/r_gBQ_qhg8U?t=9m50s) it is stated that:

> It can easily be verified that the wavefunction of a non-degenerate quantum mechanical system will be real.

However the presenter does not explain why this statement is true. How can we prove this? Does the professor assume a real Hamiltonian, i.e. one that includes only kinetic energy and Coulomb interaction terms?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A complex ground state $\psi$ can be written as $\psi_r + i\psi_i$, where $\psi_r$ and $\psi_i$ are real. Since $H\psi - E\psi = 0$ substituting for $\psi$ gives us the two equations $H\psi_r - E\psi_r = 0$ and $H\psi_i - E\psi_i = 0$. So $\psi_r$ and $\psi_i$ are both eigenfunctions of $H$ with the same energy $E$ as $\psi$, and therefore the ground state must be degenerate, which contradicts our initial assumption.

Comment: It might be better to say that the wavefunction "can be chosen to be real".  For instance in John Rennie's example you could also have $\psi_r = \psi_i$, in which case the state is not degenerate, but instead we have $\psi = (1+i)\psi_r$.  You can choose to drop the overall phase factor.

Comment: @JohnRennie 1) That should be an answer, as I'm sure you are already aware. 2) Does one need to additionally stipulate time-reversal invariance for your argument to hold?

Comment: @MarkMitchison: I answered in a comment because the question had been closed. Now it's been reopened I'll convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prove this by a reductio ad absurdum. We start by assuming that the wavefunction of a non-degenerate ground state is complex, then show this means the wavefunction must be degenerate.

Suppose we have a complex ground state. Then we can write it as a sum of real and imagniary parts:

$$ \psi = \psi_r + i\psi_i \tag{1} $$

The ground state obeys Schrodinger's equation:

$$ H\psi - E\psi = 0 $$

and if we use equation (1) to substitute for $\psi$ we get:

$$ H\psi_r + iH\psi_i - E\psi_r - Ei\psi_i = 0 $$

For a complex number to be zero both its real and imaginary parts must be zero, so we get the two equations:

$$\begin{align}
 H\psi_r - E\psi_r &= 0 \\
 H\psi_i - E\psi_i &= 0
\end{align}$$

But this means that $\psi_r$ and $\psi_i$ are also eigenstates with the same energy $E$ as $\psi$. That means $\psi$ is degenerate, and that contradicts our initial assumption.

Comment: How do you define "complex", "real" and "imaginary" part here? If someone hands you a generic Hilbert space, there is no unique notion of "real" and "imaginary" on it. Also, you need to handle the case $\psi_r = \psi_i$.

Comment: Indeed, the statement is valid for Hamiltonians of the form $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta + V(x)$ with $V$ real and referring to the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R^n,dx)$, using the usual notion of real and complex valued function...It can be extended to more general cases when there is an antilinear operator $C: \cal H \to \cal H$, surjective, isometric such that $CC=I$, commuting with the Hamiltonian operator...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Are there nontrivial examples of such $C$s which do not reduce to complex conjugation in a particular basis? It's a nice formalization (and it covers cases such as $H=\tfrac12 \hat p^2 +\hat p+\tfrac12\hat x^2$) but it feels like it could be little more than just a formalization. Or maybe there are more interesting examples out there, and if there are then I'm really curious.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Actually I do not know. Let me think about...

Comment: @Valter Fair enough. I'm glad I piqued your interest, though =).

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Take, in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, the map $(C\psi)(x)= e^{icx}\overline{\psi(x)}$, the bar denoting the complex conjugation and $c\in \mathbb R$ being a fixed real number. I believe that there is no choice of basis (proper or improper) where $C$ reduces to a simple complex conjugation. I do not know however if this example can be used in some physical context.

Comment: @ValterMoretti That feels like the same to me. If $\phi(x)$ is real, then $\psi(x)=e^{icx/2}\phi(x)$ is an eigenstate of $C$, so an improper eigenbasis of $C$ would be $\{e^{icx/2}|x⟩\}$, and that extends to a proper basis easily. Similarly, $H$ is real in the old sense (i.e. $\overline{(H\psi)(x)}=H\overline{\psi(x)}$) if and only if $HC=CH$. Unless I'm missing something obvious, which is a distinct possibility.

Comment: This proof only works when there's no magnetic field, since otherwise the Hamiltonian in position basis will have imaginary terms.