# Is there a way to prove that a bound state wavefunction can always be chosen real for an arbitrary potential in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

As we can prove many things that always (at least in introductory quantum mechanical problems) apply using an arbitrary potential (like that $E>V_{\rm min}$ or else the solutions are non-normalizable and superpositions of them can't produce normalizable wavefunctions), is there a way to generally prove for an arbitrary potential that bound states always correspond to real functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I) Yes, the [time independent Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) (TISE) of the form $$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} {\bf \nabla}^2 +V({\bf r}) -E \right) \psi({\bf r}) ~=~0 $$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and invariant$^1$ under complex conjugation. So if the wave function $\psi$ is a solution with finite square-norm, then so will $\psi^{\ast}$, 
$$\frac{\psi+\psi^{\ast}}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\psi-\psi^{\ast}}{2i}$$

be. The two latter are real solutions, and at least one of them has non-zero square-norm if $\psi$ has non-zero square-norm. Hence we can always choose a normalizable solution to be real. See also  Problem 2.1b in Griffiths, *Intro to QM,* and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/2451) related Phys.SE post.

II) Note that the same argument does *not* apply to scattering states in the continuous spectrum, since the boundary conditions at infinity of $\psi^{\ast}$ could be off.

Also it does *not* apply to the [time dependent Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) (TDSE).

--

$^1$ Here we have implicitly used that the eigenvalue $E\in\mathbb{R}$ is real because the Hamiltonian $H$ is self-adjoint. Note that self-adjointness alone is *not* enough. E.g. $$H~=~\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i} {\bf \nabla}-q {\bf A}({\bf r}) \right)^2  +V({\bf r})$$ is self-adjoint, but the corresponding TISE is *not* invariant under complex conjugation.

Comment: what about the wave functions for periodic potentials?