# Examples of Complex valued wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

After learning some rudimentary Quantum Mechanics, I have found that the wavefunctions of harmonic Oscillators and particles in potential well **are all real valued**. The ground state of harmonic oscillators, for example, has a wavefunction similar to a Normal distribution.

I wonder whether or not there are **interesting** examples complex valued wavefunctions. Since QM's formulation needs a lot of complex numbers, I think some systems must have complex valued wavefunctions.

Or can we say that all systems can be described with real valued wavefunctions?

EDIT: Really sorry for giving an unclear question. What I am going to find is a wavefunction that never become real valued after evolutioning according to the time dependent Schrodinger equation $i\hbar \frac{d|\phi>}{dt}=H |\phi>$

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/ Note that they talk about eigenstates. You can trivially obtain a complex wavefunction by a linear combination of eigenstates.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost if you take a Harmonic oscillator and try to find the time dependent wavefunction you necessarily get a complex phase factor $\lvert n\rangle \to e^{-i\hbar^{-1}E_nt}\lvert n\rangle$.

Secondly having the wavefunctions that are solutions be real values is just a convenient choice -  the wave equation being real this choice is always possible. You can multiply the wavefunction by a constant phase factor $e^{i\phi}$ and it changes nothing.

Comment: For the case of hydrogen atom, can we still always choose eigenstates to be real-valued functions?  I remember that the eigenstates consist of spherical harmonics $Y_{l}^{m_{l}}(\theta, \phi) \sim e^{i m_{l} \phi}$ which is complex for $l > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The wavefunction solution to the [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) can be chosen *real,* cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451) Phys.SE posts.
2. The wavefunction solution to the TDSE is oscillatory and therefore generically *complex.*