# Are stationary states always real functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I've noticed that for many quantum potentials, (the harmonic oscillator, the infinite square well, and the delta potential) the wavefunctions $\psi_n$ of stationary states are always real valued functions.

I couldn't explain this with observable-based arguments since only the probability distribution $\psi_n \psi_n^*$ is observable, which leaves open the possibility of complex wave-functions which nevertheless have real probability distributions.

So, is it a general principle that the wavefunctions associated with stationary states are real-valued? If so, why?  If not, are there any simple examples of potentials where this does not hold?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Eigenfunctions/Wavefunctions are real?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/)