# 1D bound state for a real potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

The prof says: "for 1Dimensional bound states with a real potential, the wave function is real, up to a phase".
The proof goes like this:

> 1D bound states are never degenerated. So $\Psi_{real}$ and $\Psi_{imaginary}$ are linearly dependent. So $\Psi \equiv \Psi_{real} +i\Psi_{imaginary}=\Psi_{real} (1+ic)=(1+c^2)e^{iArg(1+ic)}\Psi_{real}$

Whatever the proof, I don't understand the statement since ***any** complex number (the wavefunction is one complex number) is in some way real up to a phase.* So I don't really understand what this theorem is trying to teach us.

PS: I cannot ask directly the professor because I study from a video recorded 6 years ago

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451 and links therein.

Comment: From the [second post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77894/when-eigenfunctions-wavefunctions-are-real), xebtl wrote _all the bound states can simultaneously be made real_ ... Does that mean that the $c$ constant (from my proof) can be cancelled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the wavefunction $\psi(\vec{r})$ is not just 1 complex number: it is infinitely many complex numbers, 1 for each value of position $\vec{r}$. In contrast, the professor is making the non-trivial statement that there exists a global (i.e. $\vec{r}$-independent) complex constant $c$.

For more details, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77894/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451) related Phys.SE posts.