# How this wave function was separated into odd and even wave functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, parity

[image]

In one of the problems in 8.04 problem set, the wave function given (29) has both growing exponential and a decaying exponential which is an even function by itself. But they are splitting it into odd and even function again using $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$?
They say $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ are the odd and even combination for real exponentials (which is true). but how is it possible to split combination real exponentials as $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13980/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-independent Schrödinger function: If the potential $V$ is even, then the wave function $\psi$ can always be taken to be either even or odd](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/)

Comment: Actually the fact that if V is even then Psi can be even or odd is fine for me. But only for this specific function how they say even function is cosh(kx) and odd function is sinh(kx) for exp(kx) + exp(-kx)

Comment: Because that’s how they are defined. You can look at the plots of the hyperbolic functions and see that cosh (sum) is even and sinh (difference) is odd.

Comment: @FellowTraveller That's true. but in the original wave function we only have the sum. right?

Comment: @NiranjanSD, yes but the coefficient D can be negative.

Comment: @FellowTraveller Thanks thats what I missed. So there can be two solutions based on the coefficients where one is odd and other is even

Comment: Yup. That’s right. Now if you normalise them you’ll see that it’s nothing but the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic are asking about the original problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Arbitrary combinations of the two functions is not even or odd. $$f(x)=Ae^{\kappa x}+B e^{-\kappa x} $$
$$f(-x)= Ae^{-\kappa x}+B e^{\kappa x}$$
Now if we impose $f(x)=\pm f(-x)$, we get the condition:
$$A=\pm B$$
This is nothing but the combinations for the hyperbolic trigonometric functions. 
$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take your (29) and replace $x\to -x$ to get
\begin{align}
\psi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l} Ae^{-\kappa x} \\ Ce^{-\kappa x} +De^{\kappa x}\\ F e^{\kappa x}\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
and compare with your initial (29).

Clearly to get $+\psi(x)$ back you need $A=F$ and $C=D$: this produces an even function since by construction $\psi(x)=\psi(-x)$.

To get $-\psi(x)$ you need $A=-F$ and $C=-D$, which produces an odd function since $\psi(x)=-\psi(-x)$.