# Missing parity of free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, parity

in this [Definite Parity of Solutions to a Schrödinger Equation with even Potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13980/) post in David Z's answer it's stated that the eigenfunctions have parity if the potential has parity/if $[H,P]=0$. In the case of a free particle the potential has parity ($V(x)=V(-x)=0$) and also the commutator vanishes since
$$
[H,P]\Psi\propto\frac{\partial^2\Psi(-x)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2\Psi(x)}{\partial x^2}\Bigg|_{x\rightarrow -x}=(-1)^2\Psi''(-x)-\Psi''(-x)=0
$$
But the general solution for the free particle $\Psi(x)=e^{ikx}$ with $k^2=\frac{2Em}{\hbar}$ has no parity:
$$
\Psi(-x)=cos(-x)+isin(-x)=cos(x)-isin(x)=-\Psi(x)+2cos(x)
$$
Why is that ?

Comment: It's not that every solution has definite parity, it's that you can _choose_ a set of solutions which each have definite parity. In this case they're $\cos(kx)$ and $\sin(kx)$, not $e^{\pm ikx}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44003/2451